# Tooltip on bootstrap checkbox label doesn't hide when marking / clearing the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

This will show a tooltip when hovering over the label of a checkbox and hide when not hovering.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin: 2em 0 0 2em">
  <label id="checkbox-label">
  <input type="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#checkbox-label').tooltip({
  title: "This tooltip won't disappear when the checkbox is checked.",
  placement: "right"
})
```

The problem is when a user checks or unchecks the checkbox, the tooltip doesn't hide until the user clicks somewhere else on the screen.

How can I make this tooltip disappear when the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Here's a JS Fiddle reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/eLax5hdq/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI although this has been answered.

For future reference when the tooptip is about to be shown bootstrap fires the show.bs.tooltip event. This way you can conditionally check for something. if you pass the event to the function you can run event.preventDefault() if the condition fails and you do not want the tooltip to show.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/eLax5hdq/9/

```
$('#checkbox-label').on('show.bs.tooltip change', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    if (e.type == 'show' && $this.find(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.type == 'change') {
        $this.find(":checkbox").is(":checked") ? $this.tooltip('hide') : $this.tooltip('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, but came up with a different solution:

```
$('#checkbox-label').on('show.bs.tooltip change', function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).tooltip("hide")` and not `$(this).tooltip("close")` as `.tooltip()` dose not support a parameter with the value `"close"`.

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLax5hdq/6/)

As noted in the [**Bootstrap documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) the methods that `tooltip` supports are: `.tooltip('hide')`, `.tooltip('show')`, `.tooltip('toggle')`, and `.tooltip('destroy')`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried 'destroy', but that didn't work on the full website. 'hide' works great.

Comment: Not working perfectly... the tool-tip still being shown after you move the mouse in and out more than once.

Comment: @Alvaro This answer dose not intend to remove that part, change it to `$(this).tooltip("destroy");` if you want the tool-tip to be gone completely. The user didn't want to remove the tool-tip on hover, only that the item to be hidden on clicked during the hover. The other answer has nice functionality and is what you would expect it to look like, but it's not what the OP asked.

Comment: Right, I got it. If you update your answer I'll be able to remove my downvote. Can't right now.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with an easier solution, but I'll leave the accepted answer as is.

Bootstrap shows a tooltip on hover *and* focus by default. Clicking on the checkbox left the element in focus, which is why the tooltip wouldn't hide without some extra code, as shown in the other two answers to this question.

The fix was to specify that I only want the tooltip on hover by adding `data-trigger="hover"` to the `<label>` element.

In summary, change this:

```
<div>
  <label id="checkbox-label">
    <input type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div>
  <label id="checkbox-label" data-trigger="hover">
    <input type="checkbox">Checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for trigger is 'hover focus', thus the tooltip stay visible after a button is clicked, until another button is clicked, because the button is focused.

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
trigger : 'hover'
})